# Allow Jenkins to send email to non registered users

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

My Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
try {

      sh 'exit 1'

      stage("Test") {
         sh "node -v"
         sh "npm prune"
         sh "npm install"
         sh "npm test"
      }
      ...

  } catch(e) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
    emailext(body: '${DEFAULT_CONTENT}', mimeType: 'text/html',
             replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO', subject: '${DEFAULT_SUBJECT}',
             to: emailextrecipients([[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'],
                                     [$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],
                                     [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]))
    throw e
  }
```

I want to send email only on build failures.
I receive following :

> Not sending mail to unregistered user my_primary_github_email@gmail.com

Actually, I have 2 questions.

1. Is there way to allow sending emails to unregistered users?
2. Is there way to configure Jenkins to send email to recipient address configured for that repository organization?
   For example:
   I have 2 emails configured in Github, primary email and secondary email, the second configured to receive emails for organizations`s repositories.
   So if the build belongs to organization, I want Jenkins to send email to address configured for that organization and not to primary address.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below line in your jenkins startup script

> -Dhudson.tasks.MailSender.SEND_TO_UNKNOWN_USERS=true

The newest Jenkins security directive only allow sending mail to registered user. The line above bypass this configuration.